# Change version of php via cron

Tags: php, cron

I am running some older software that can not be updated due to hardware limitations.

This software runs a current version of PHP, however one aspect needs to run on the previous version, but is an automated task that only needs a ten minute window daily.

It is currently being switched manually, but I was wondering if a cron could be set up to switch the version of PHP running on the server to the older version, then switch back to the newer version of PHP after ten minutes.

Comment: Changing the installed version of PHP seems like a very fragile way to do this. Can't you just invoke it like `/usr/bin/php5` and `/usr/bin/php7` to get the desired version?

Comment: I agree with Balmar, why does it need 10 minutes? Can't you just execute the file with the PHP version you want it to run? This way the server can stay operational 24/7.

Answer (score 5):

you can run as many php version on the server as you like, as a cron job you can just specify the php version used based on its path, so your cron job could look like

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php5.2 file.php
```

Comment: Nice! I assumed that he needed to run an old version wholesale due to a complex php solution.  I like your solution for one file. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a cron line to do the following at the appropriate times.

```
a2dismod php5.6
a2enmod php7.2
service apache2 restart
```

The above, are the commands that will switch your versions.  This must be done with the appropriate permissions.  Typically with sudo.  So, you will want to edit your cron file (crontab -e) while under sudo.

line to switch to 5.6

```
0 1 * * * service apache2 stop; a2dismod php7.2; a2enmod php5.6; service apache2 start
10 1 * * * service apache2 stop; a2dismod php5.6; a2enmod php7.2; service apache2 start
```

You may wish to cause output to send to /dev/null to prevent files from piling up in the home directory.

In the case above, at 1am each night, 5.6 will be enabled.  And at 1:10am each night, 7.2 will be re-enabled.